# How to instantiate a type named like a function

Tags: c++, identifier

Apparently C++ lets you define both a struct/class **and** a function with the same name like this:

```
struct Foo {
    int foo;
    Foo(int foo) : foo(foo) {}
};

void Foo(int foo) {}

int main() {
    // Works, calls function
    Foo(42);

    // Doesn't work - compiler error
    Foo foo(42);
}
```

Is this the expected behaviour? 
How to create a instance of the Foo struct?
How to avoid that some added library defining a function named like a type in your project causes compiler errors all over the place?

Comment: `namespace`s are the way to avoid name clashes.

Comment: @arne: `namespace`s are imho more to shorten names in certain contexts, to avoid name clashes, you don't need namespaces (see e.g. many C libraries), but good, probably unique names. Unique names tend to be long, and namespaces are to shorten these long names.

Comment: @phresnel: `namespace`s are not to shorten names. They are absolutely for encapsulation. 50 "possibly unique" names are not as useful as 50 "definitely unique" names in 1 "very likely unique" namespace. Both are ultimately valid goals of using them, though.

Comment: Is there a workaround? - yes CAN you do it? - yes. But every time you do it, a baby seal dies.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What is the effective difference between `gl::begin()` and `glBegin()` (example from OpenGL) with respect to uniqueness? With only respect to uniqueness, one could go so far and argue that `glBegin()` will nameclash less than `begin()`? (note: I am all for namespaces, but not because of alleged uniqueness)

Comment: @phresnel: You picked a pretty benign example wherein GL's function names are both highly-likely-unique in their own right (`glCopyTexImage1D`) and also, of course, prefixed with `gl`, which is also an uncommon name. This combination makes this one of the better examples of your proposition and one of the worse examples of mine. _[..]_

Comment: _[..]_ But that's not the only example you can construct. A library function called `clearPage` is not so obviously unique and, sure, you can disambiguate with your prefixes but that's where the argument for _semantic_ prefixes come in: namespaces, with all the benefits they have to offer including the scope rules and `using` statements.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, but then the argument is no longer "uniqueness" in its own, but semantics and context. The latter being, in my humble opinion, the _real_ aspects of namespaces; that you can have short, self explaining names (`begin`, `end`) when you can (and should), and probably unique names when you must (`std::begin`, `gl::begin`; which are then (which was the point I tried to make) not more powerful then `stdBegin` and `glBegin`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. There is no general way to say "I meant the class, not the function, with this name" because you are not supposed to re-use names.

`typename` cannot help you here, though since `Foo` is a class and C++ provides backward compatibility with C's `struct T` type syntax, you can say `class Foo` or `struct Foo` instead:

```
int main() {
    // Calls function
    Foo(42);

    // Constructs a `[class] Foo`
    class Foo foo(42);
}
```

This is something of a hack, though, and doesn't really solve the fundamental problem which is that the symbols in your program are not clearly differentiated from one another.

Depending on your real circumstances, a *namespace* might solve your problem in a robust and *clear* way. Libraries *should* be using them (but often don't).

Otherwise simply improve your names... and I don't mean by calling one `Foo` and the other `FooClass`!

Comment: If you are not supposed to reuse names then why would the compiler let you do so? Defining a function named like a type in C gives a compiler error, however compiles in C++

Comment: @BillAskaga: There are many, _many_ things that you are not supposed to do in C++ which the compiler will let you do anyway. Some of these are because the compiler doesn't care, and some are because the standard deliberately says it won't bother prohibiting the situation and you have to simply deal with the repercussions (see: UB). In all cases, though, it's up to the _programmer_ to write decent code and the compiler is generally not keen to hold your hand in all but the most obviously impossible scenarios.

Comment: A similar example is `int i = 42; for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { /* What is i? */ } /* What is i? */` It makes for very poor code to reuse names like this, but it's not important enough for the compiler to bother stopping you from doing it.

Answer (score 4):

You can write `struct` or `class` when you mean the type:

```
struct Foo foo(42);
class Foo bar(0xdeadbeef);
```